# What does a green colored file name mean?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I downloaded a .zip file the other day and extracted it using 7zip from my desktop to my laptop over my home network, when it finished, its filename and the filename of its contents was *green*.

What does this mean, can i revert it to normal, has anything been modified and is there a list somewhere of color codes for windows file names.. ? *(I can recall seeing blue somewhere before).*

[image]
[image]